# what is this `http` after `:` when i execute `netstat -N -e -p -l -a F` in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, port

so i execute `netstat -N -e -p -l -a f` to see which port my program is listening on but i notice somethin is in foreign address colum i see "`http`" after : but i thought there will be a port number after i know what is http (hyper text transfer protocal) so how will i found out those foreign address port i just want to know those foreign address port that they are running on (not on my network on their network) here is the output of the command

```
netstat -N -e -p -l -a F
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:59872         117.18.237.29:http      ESTABLISHED kali       31750      1620/firefox-esr    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:49466         74.125.24.94:http       ESTABLISHED kali       26603      1620/firefox-esr    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:35518         sa-in-f154.1e100.:https ESTABLISHED kali       30521      1620/firefox-esr    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:41376         74.125.24.102:https     ESTABLISHED kali       31072      1620/firefox-esr    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:33038         172.217.194.84:https    ESTABLISHED kali       31914      1620/firefox-esr    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:46684         172.217.194.138:https   ESTABLISHED kali       32811      1620/firefox-esr    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:47164         172.217.194.95:https    ESTABLISHED kali       27485      1620/firefox-esr    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:47446         sa-in-f155.1e100.:https ESTABLISHED kali       31865      1620/firefox-esr    
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:54410         172.217.194.119:https   ESTABLISHED kali       3287
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the port number, found through `/etc/services`.